Is the "box convolution" a linear constraint?
I have a system of linear inequalities $\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}$; we'll denote the set of solutions by $F$.
I want to consider the superset $F^*\supseteq F$ defined by $\{\mathbf{y}  : \mathbf{x} \in F, \mathbf{y} \geq \mathbf{x}\}$, where $\mathbf{y}\geq \mathbf{x}$ means that $y_i \geq x_i$ in each component. In other words, this is a union of "upward boxes" centered on each point in $F$.
I am wondering if $F^*$ is defined by a system of linear inequalities as well, whenever $F$ is.  When I consider the 1- and 2-dimensional problem, I observe that (a) small changes in $\mathbf{A}$ discontinuously affect the set $F^*$, (b) $F^*$ does indeed seem to be defined by the system of linear inequalities, and in fact seems to be either $\varnothing, F, $ or $\mathbb{R}^n$.
But I'm not sure how to tell what it does in higher dimensions, or how to derive the linear constraints that define $F^*$ from the constraints that define $F$, assuming they exist.

I don't think conjecture $(b)$ is true. Consider $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ being the triangle with corners $(0, 0)$, $(1, 0)$, and $(0, 1)$. $F^*$ is the whole first quadrant.

@msantama Thanks, you're right! I should've said that the toy examples I was thinking through involved single boundaries in 1D and 2D rather than systems.

I'm not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking whether $F^$ is defined by a system of linear inequalities over only the variables $x$ but not any additional variables?  i.e., if $x$ has dimension $d$, then you want a system of linear equations over $d$ unknowns that defines $F^$?  If you allow additional variables, then sure, $F^*$ is the set of solution $x$ to the linear inequalities $At\le b$, $t \le x$.  Please [edit] the question to clarify what you are asking, and what it means to be "defined by a system of linear inequalities".

Yes.  $F^*$ is defined by a system of linear inequalities.
You have $F=\{x \mid Ax\le b\}$ and $F^*=\{x \mid At\le b, t \le x\}$.  This is one sense in which $F^*$ is already defined by a system of linear inequalities.
Alternatively, if you want to avoid any additional variables, note that $F^*=\{x \mid \exists t . (At\le b, t\le x)\}$, then apply Fourier-Motzkin elimination to the variables $t$.  Fourier-Motzkin elimination finds an equivalent system of linear equations over $x$, that do not contain $t$, so it finds a system of the form $Bx \le c$, so that $F^*=\{x \mid Bx\le c\}$.  The number of linear inequalities might increase exponentially, I think.
